# Accuaracy problem with internal ADC in esp32

Tags: c, arduino, esp32, adc

My circuit to measure battery right now is esp32, nrf24l01, and 18650. I powered up esp32 with 18650 3.6V nominal/4.2 max battery. Run a voltage divider 100k, 27k then it's 0.893V a measure point. At 3.6V measure point like ~0.72.

I use internal 1.1V ADC but why I only receive ~3V at monitor
[image: My circuit]

```
float battery_read()
{
    //read battery voltage per %
    long sum = 0;                  // sum of samples taken
    float voltage = 0.0;           // calculated voltage
    float output = 0.0;            //output value
    const float battery_max = 4.2; //maximum voltage of battery
    const float battery_min = 3.0; //minimum voltage of battery before shutdown

    float R1 = 100000.0; // resistance of R1 (100K)
    float R2 = 27000.0;  // resistance of R2 (10K)

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        sum += adc1_get_voltage(ADC1_CHANNEL_0);
        delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // calculate the voltage*/

    voltage = sum / (float)100;
    Serial.println(voltage);
    voltage = (voltage *1.1) / 2047.0; //for internal 1.1v reference
    // use if added divider circuit
    voltage = voltage / (R2/(R1+R2));
```

Comment: When you actually use an accurate multimeter at the ADC input, what voltage do you see?

Comment: i use VOM then my VBat is 3.62, 0.7xx at ADC input. from the code i just monitor VIN = VOUT/factor. it was around 3.0V

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using ESP32-WROOM-32 module.

Your register divider should be connected to SENSOR_VP (VP) pin if you wish to read from channel ADC1_CHANNEL_0 and not EN pin.

ADC1_CHANNEL_0 is mapped to SENSOR_VP (VP) pin.

Your EN pin should be to +3.3VDC through an RC network (R-> 10k and C-> 0.1uF). I doubt if your module is even booting as it is active high and needs 150uS delay before going high after every reset.

Make sure you execute `adc1_config_width()` and `adc1_config_channel_atten()` before the first time `adc1_get_voltage()` is called.

Comment: My mistake, i actually connected to GPIO36. i also run `adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_11);` and
`adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_0,ADC_ATTEN_DB_0);`. Do you have any idea about the diferenced between VOM and adc measurement

Comment: What is the value returned by `adc1_get_voltage()`? Is it coming close to 1302.

Comment: no. it's around 1215. [here is my circuit](https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/z1441710576761-a9c7c4541ccba6eef0366b2f8d6416fb.BtpaiE). i actually connected to gpio36.

Comment: Is your battery voltage approximate to 3.07 volts.

Comment: no my battery is 3.3v or 3.6v. this topic fixed that problem [
ESP32-WROOM battery measuring](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2158). there is also a example code for calibration